# Django: Could not parse the remainder: '"{%' from '"{%'

Tags: django

I'm using Django and I'm getting an "Error during template rendering": "Could not parse the remainder: '"{%' from '"{%' ".
Here is the line of code causing the problem:

```
{% with memberName="Java" memberPhoto="{% static 'sbs/images/avatar.jpg' %}" memberYear=80 memberBio="Lorem ipsum dalas dolores blabla" %} {% include "sbs/_member.html" %} {% endwith %}
```

It is happening because of the image, but how could i put the image as a variable here without getting this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot nest `{% ... %}`s. Use the `as` clause of the `static` tag to store the static URL into a variable first:

```
{% static 'sbs/images/avatar.jpg' as avatar %}
{% with memberName="Java" memberPhoto=avatar memberYear=80 memberBio="Lorem ipsum dalas dolores blabla" %}
{% include "sbs/_member.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```